# How to save a clone of an entity as an update with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I don't like to use setters as I don't like to mutate objects once they're instantiated, so I tend to use the `withFoo(Foo $foo)` style that returns a clone, instead:

```
public function withFoo(Foo $foo): self
{
    $clone = clone $this;
    $clone->foo = $foo;
    return $clone;
}
```

This has served me really well for a long time, but now I have to work with Doctrine2 and it doesn't work:

```
$foo = $fooRepository->getByBar($bar);
$foo = $foo->withBaz($baz);
$emi->flush();
```

This results in an error in my logs something like this:

```
app.ERROR: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO foo (id, bar, baz) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["51f74f6e-8e20-42ec-ba21-ac3ae62658ef", "Bar", "Baz"]:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '51f74f6e-8e20-42ec-ba21-ac3ae62658ef' for key 'PRIMARY' [] []
```

If I change my code to the following, it will update no problem:

```
public function withFoo(Foo $foo): self
{
    $this->foo = $foo;
    return $this;
}
```

For now I've had to resort to using a normal setter, but I don't like it. Is there a way to do this?

I want to tell it to save the update, but to use the ID to determine which record to update. Sort of a `REPLACE INTO` in MySQL, for example.

Any help?

Comment: Take a look at the entity manager's [detach and merge](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) functionality.  Never tried it with clone but it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad. I'm done for the day now but will give it a shot tomorrow morning 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks to @Cerad who made the suggestion in the comments on my question. I did indeed need the [detach and merge](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) functionality. So the entity has the `withBar(Bar $bar)` method:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo", ...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Bar
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="object" ...)
     */
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(string $id, Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function withBar(Bar $bar): self
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        $clone->bar = $bar;
        return $clone;
    }
}
```

That works as it did in projects that didn't use Doctrine, by returning a modified **COPY** of the original, rather than mutating it. Happy with that.

Next, the `FooRepository` update method becomes something like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Foo;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class FooRepository
{
    private $emi, $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $emi)
    {
        $this->emi = $emi;
        $this->repository = $emi->getRepository(Foo::class);
    }

    public function updateBar(string $id, Bar $bar): Foo
    {
        // Get the `Foo` and update the `Bar`
        $foo = $this->repository->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);
        $foo = $foo->withBar($bar);

        // Detach and merge the entity
        // You can do the detach before the `withBar()` but it makes no difference
        // as the modified entity is actually an entirely new object, so Doctrine
        // can't see it until it's merged anyway
        $this->emi->detach($foo);
        $this->emi->merge($foo);
        $this->emi->flush();

        return $foo;
    }
}
```

*Error handling deliberately omitted as the examples are contrived anyway*

Thank you for the pointer. If you'd written it as an answer I would've happily accepted it and given you the rep